# Loading Jscript files into Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

Let's get directly to the problem :

I'm actually doing a firefox extension in which i would like to implement the jWebsocket API in order to build a small chat.
I got my main script file, named *test.js*, and the jWebsocket lib into a js folder.
Just for you to know, this is my first firefox extension ever.

So in my XUL file I got this (for the script part only of course, the interface code is not shown) :

```
    <overlay id="test-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://test/content/test.js" />
  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://test/content/js/jwebsocket.js" />
```

*jwebsocket.js* being the file I need to call according to jWebsocket website.

In my main script file *test.js* I start with :

```
if (jws.browserSupportsWebSockets()) 
{
  jWebSocketClient = new jws.jWebSocketJSONClient();
} 
else 
{
  var lMsg = jws.MSG_WS_NOT_SUPPORTED;
  alert(lMsg);
}
```

jws being the namespace created into the *jwebsocket.js* file.

Of course I've got the required stand-alone server running in background, and working.

So from what I understood looking on various websites, is that if a js file is loaded into the javascript allocated memory space (with the  tag), all namespace/function should be available between each file. But this was mostly for HTML-oriented issues, so I'm not sure if it applies to XUL/Firefox environment.

But the script keep failing at the first jws call.

Any ideas on what goes wrong here ? I'm stuck for 2 days now :/

Comment: I don't know much about extensions, but shouldn't the library script file go *before* the code that uses it?

Comment: Also, I'm kind-of doubting that the jwebsockets thing is going to work in the XUL context.

Comment: Already try to switch order, no changes :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is the same of HTML developing, you have your namespace avaiable between each XUL file.
Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/JavaScript_Object_Management) for namespacing in firefox extensions.

What error do you get?

**Edit:**

Do you have initialized your jws object before to call browserSupportsWebSockets() ?

Like Pointy said, you need to load test.js *after* your jwebsocket.js file.

Comment: Thank you for the link, the jwebsocket namespace seems to be well-formed.

And I do not get any error, I placed an *alert* before and after the block of code I posted, the first one works, not the second, and the code is just supposed to create an *jWebSocketJSONClient*.

Comment: Place the alert inside if and else, before the assignation, so you can get what the code executes

Comment: Well...no I didn't. How can I do that ? Sry I am not really into javascript. (But the jwebsocket is now loaded before, but as I said no changes)

EDIT : no alert fires up between if or else, so it must fail when calling the *jws.browserSupportsWebSockets()*

Comment: I think it would be better if you post an example of how the jws object is structured.

Comment: I think that code wouldn't run in a firefox extension simply including it. In firefox extensions you are subject to some restrictions that could block some parts of that code.

Comment: Arg :/ What make you think that, regarding the jwebsocket.js code ? (I'm just being curious) Or do you have any links relative to those "restrictions" ? Anyway thanks for your help, it is appreciated :)